# is it allowed to pass *this as an argument of a function accepting a reference(&)?

Tags: c++

I have been using this method without any problem, but I want to make sure if this is a totally allowed approach or I am just being lucky!

```
class A
{
public:
    void bar()
    {
        foo(*this);
    }
};

void foo(A &a)
{

}
```

thank you

Answer (score 6, accepted):

As long as `void Foo(A&)` is *(forward) declared* so that `A::bar` knows about its existance it's fully valid and 100% allowed.

---

**Notes**

- Is there anywhere I may not dereference `this`?

  Not really, but there are a few issues you should know about. If you want to use `*this` in the initialization list of a constructing object please remember that you are **not** allowed to access *virtual* or *uninitialized* members of that object through it; neither directly nor indirectly.
- if the *member-function* is declared `const` only functions taking a *const (reference)* are allowed to be called using a dereferenced `this`-pointer, see the below example.

```
void func (struct Obj&);
void func (struct Obj const&);

struct Obj {
  void bar () const {
    func (*this);
  }

  void bar () {
    func (*this);
  }
};
```

```
int
main (int argc, char *argv[])
{
  Obj       a;  
  Obj const b;

  a.bar (); /* func (Obj &) */
  b.bar (); /* func (Obj const&) */
}
```

Answer (score 4):

Yes, it's allowed. Note that from a const method, you can pass `*this` only to functions accepting const parameters:

```
class B;

void foo(B&);
void bar(B const&);

class B {
  void meow() const {
    bar(*this); //OK
    foo(*this); //ERROR
  }
};
```

Answer (score 1):

Yes, it is perfectly legal. This is what you do when you write `return *this;` in some operators (like assignment operator).

Answer (score 1):

This is perfectly fine, and a common pattern for "I want some other function or object to know about this object".

Just make sure that the reference isn't saved beyond the lifetime of the one passed in.